# REFLECTION Invoking a Method with List<Class> Parameter

Tags: c#, .net

i have this escenario:

i want to invoke a method that acepts List argument.

Parameter : List
when i Execute this lines:

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(nameMethod);
object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, null);
object[] parametersArray = new object[] { Parameter == null ? Activator.CreateInstance(tipoEntidad, null) : Parameter };

objeto = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, parametersArray);
```

its thrown this Error:

> innerException:  {"El formateador inició una excepción al intentar
>   deserializar el mensaje: Error al intentar deserializar el parámetro
>   link:tempuri.org:lpdv. El mensaje de InnerException era 'Error en la
>   línea 1, posición 342. El elemento
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays:anyType'
>   contiene datos de un tipo que coincide con el nombre
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Entitys:Pdv'. El
>   deserializador no tiene conocimiento de ningún tipo que esté asignado
>   a este nombre. Intente usar DataContractResolver o agregar el tipo
>   correspondiente a 'PuntoVenta' a la lista de tipos conocidos (por
>   ejemplo, usando el atributo KnownTypeAttribute o agregándolo a la
>   lista de tipos conocidos que se pasa a DataContractSerializer).'.
>   Consulte InnerException para obtener más información."}

this only happends when Parameter is List if Parameter its Pdv it Works Correctly, ¿What can i do?

Comment: you should translate the error, at least

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
        [Test]
        public void T1()
        {

            var type = typeof (classwithListmethod);

            MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("List");
            object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, null);

            var list = new List<string>(){"one","two"};
            var a = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, new []{list});
        }


        public class classwithListmethod
        {
            public void List(List<string> s)
            {
                foreach (var ss in s)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ss);
                }
            }

        }
```